# How can I call a shell command in my Perl script?

Tags: perl

What would be an example of how I can call a shell command, say '`ls -a`' in a Perl script and the way to retrieve the output of the command as well?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

[How to run a shell script from a Perl program](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=78523)

> **1. Using system `system($command, @arguments);`**
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> system("sh", "script.sh", "--help" );
>
> system("sh script.sh --help");
> ```
>
> System will execute the $command with
>   @arguments and return to your script when finished. You may check $!
>   for certain errors passed to the OS by the external application. Read
>   the documentation for system for the nuances of how various
>   invocations are slightly different.
>
> **2. Using `exec`**
>
> This is very similar to the use of [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html), but it will
>   terminate your script upon execution. Again, read the documentation
>   for [exec](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) for more.
>
> **3. Using backticks or `qx//`**
>
> ```
> my $output = `script.sh --option`;
>
> my $output = qx/script.sh --option/;
> ```
>
> The backtick operator and it's equivalent `qx//`, excute the command and options inside the operator and return that commands output to STDOUT when it finishes.
>
> There are also ways to run external applications through creative use of [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), but this is advanced use; read the documentation for more.

Comment: system() gives u output in run time.

Comment: I don't think tilda ` works with latest perl(5.24.0)

Comment: That is called a backtick ` ... for programming anyway, when used in foreign languages it is an accent. A tilde (notice the "e" at the end, rather than "a") is the squiggly line; which in Perl is used for pattern matching and smart matching.

Comment: for the qx/ or backtick one add 2>&1 to capture also stderr.

Answer (score 30):

From [Perl HowTo](http://www.perlhowto.com/executing_external_commands), the most common ways to execute external commands from Perl are:

- `` my $files = `ls -la` `` — captures the output of the command in `$files`
- `system "touch ~/foo"` — if you don't want to capture the command's output
- `exec "vim ~/foo"` — if you don't want to return to the script after executing the command
- `open(my $file, '|-', "grep foo"); print $file "foo\nbar"` — if you want to pipe input into the command

Answer (score 18):

### Examples

1. `` `ls -l`; ``
2. `system("ls -l");`
3. `exec("ls -l");`

Comment: You should explain what are the differences between these methods. Also, I believe not all of them solve the problem that OP has (calling exec does not return to the perl script AFAIR)

Comment: @K.L. You are correct, without some nasty hacks exec will exit the perl script with the same exit code as the passed command.

Answer (score 13):

As you become more experienced with using Perl, you'll find that there are fewer and fewer occasions when you need to run shell commands.  For example, one way to get a list of files is to use Perl's built-in [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) function.  If you want the list in sorted order you could combine it with the built-in [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) function.  If you want details about each file, you can use the [stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) function.  Here's an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $file ( sort glob('/home/grant/*') ) {
    my($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size,$atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks)
        = stat($file);
    printf("%-40s %8u bytes\n", $file, $size);
}
```

Comment: Obviously this answer doesn't apply to commands other than `ls`, but in the case that the user was actually going to call `ls`, this answer deserves recognition for answering the user's intention rather than their actual question.

Answer (score 12):

Look at the [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) function in Perl - especially the variants using a '|' (pipe) in the arguments.  Done correctly, you'll get a file handle that you can use to read the output of the command.  The back tick operators also do this.

You might also want to review whether Perl has access to the C functions that the command itself uses.  For example, for `ls -a`, you could use the [opendir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html) function, and then read the file names with the [readdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) function, and finally close the directory with (surprise) the [closedir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/closedir.html) function.  This has a number of benefits - precision probably being more important than speed.  Using these functions, you can get the correct data even if the file names contain odd characters like newline.

Answer (score 6):

There are a lot of ways you can call a shell command from a Perl script, such as:

1. back tick
          `ls` which captures the output and gives back to you.
2. system
          system('ls');
3. open

Refer #17 here: [Perl programming tips](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/20-killer-perl-programming-tips-for-beginners-on-unix-linux-os/)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [open2](http://search.cpan.org/~dapm/perl-5.10.1/lib/IPC/Open2.pm) and [open3](http://search.cpan.org/~dapm/perl-5.10.1/lib/IPC/Open3.pm) in case you need bidirectional communication.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using system and qq to run linux programs inside perl. And it has worked well.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl   # A hashbang line in perl
    
use strict;       # It can save you a lot of time and headache
use warnings;     # It helps you find typing mistakes

# my keyword in Perl declares the listed variable

my $adduser = '/usr/sbin/adduser';
my $edquota = '/usr/sbin/edquota';
my $chage = '/usr/bin/chage';
my $quota = '/usr/bin/quota';
my $nomeinteiro;
my $username;
my $home;


# system() function executes a system shell command
# qq() can be used in place of double quotes

system qq($adduser --home $home --gecos "$fullname" $username);
system qq($edquota -p john $username);
system qq($chage -E \$(date -d +180days +%Y-%m-%d) $username);
system qq($chage -l $username);
system qq($quota -s $username);
```

Comment: The answer would be more useful if you can add some explanation along with the code.

Comment: Thanks for the review. now I put more comments to get a better understanding.