# Call a bash script from a perl script

Tags: perl, bash

I am trying a code in perl script and need to call another file in bash.
Not sure, which is the best way to do that? can I directly call it using system() ?
Please guide/ show me a sample way.

from what I have tried so far :

```
     #!/usr/bin/perl
     system("bash bashscript.sh");
```

Bash :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "cdto codespace ..."
cd codetest
rm -rf cts
for sufix in a o exe ; do
echo ${sufix}
find . -depth -type f -name "*.${sufix}" -exec rm -f {} \;
done
```

I am getting an error when I execute the perl script : 
 No such file or directory codetest

syntax error near unexpected token `do

Comment: yes, you can using `system("bash -c script.sh")`,  for example

Comment: @IgorChubin you're right , but if script has execution than `bash -c` is ok too

Comment: I solved my first problem according to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script :
alias proj="cd /home/tree/projects/java"
(Thanks to @Greg Hewgill)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I call a shell command in my Perl script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3200801/608639)

Answer (score 11):

If you just want run you script you can use backticks or system:

```
$result = `/bin/bash /path/to/script`;
```

or

```
system("/bin/bash /path/to/script");
```

If your script produces bug amount of data,
the best way to run it is to use open + pipe:

```
if open(PIPE, "/bin/bash /path/to/script|") {
  while(<PIPE>){
  }
}
else {
  # can't run the script
  die "Can't run the script: $!";
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but /bin/sh may not be bash, and if it is bash will run in --posix mode.

Comment: No reason to run `sh` just to launch `bash`: `system("/bin/bash", "/path/to/script");` and `open(my $PIPE, '-|', "/bin/bash", "/path/to/script")` would avoid this.

Comment: also just `\`bash script.sh\`` could be used

Comment: @IgorChubin What does the `$!` do at the end of your code? I'm unfamiliar with Perl.

Comment: @IgorChubin Is the `|` necessary at the end of `"/bin/bash /path/to/script|")?  What does that do?

Comment: @MrPickles: Yes, it's necessary. that is actually the main point. Without the pipe symbol you will just open a file with the name in the quotes (it does not exist, obviously, because it'a a command name). And now what is `$!`: that is a special variable, containing error message in it

Answer (score 1):

You can use backticks to execute commands:

```
$command = `command arg1 arg2`;
```

There are several other additional methods, including `system("command arg1 arg2")` to execute them as well.

Here's a good online reference: http://www.perlhowto.com/executing_external_commands

Answer (score 1):

You can use backticks, system(), or exec.

```
  system("myscript.sh") == 0
    or die "Bash Script failed";
```

See also: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799968/whats-the-difference-between-perls-backticks-system-and-exec) post.

Comment: backticks in void context… use system() and save some extra work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my first problem according to  [Why doesn't "cd" work in a bash shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script) :

```
alias proj="cd /home/tree/projects/java"
```

(Thanks to @Greg Hewgill)