# How to comma seperate console output returned from perl script

Tags: perl, bash

As stated here in [Call a bash script from a perl script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636721/call-a-bash-script-from-a-perl-script) by Igor Chubin, one way to retrieve the result of a bash script from within a perl script is by:

```
    $result = `/bin/bash /path/to/script`;
```

Now, my result is actually a series of files, because this script runs a simple find command. The result on the console looks like:

```
    /path/to/file.extension
    /path/to/file2.extension
```

I want to take the result, remove white spaces, and concatenate file names seperated with a comma. So that my `$result` looks like:

```
    /path/to/file.extension,/path/to/file2.extension
```

What is the most efficient way to do this? Note that this is taking place within a perl script.

Comment: why do you want to remove white spaces?

Comment: Using the perl script, the result is fed into a java program as a comma seperated string

Comment: @mpapec you're right. no need to remove white spaces, replacing the new line with a comma does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 chomp($result);
 $result =~ tr|\n|,|; # replace every newline with comma
 $result =~ s|\s+||g; # remove whitespaces
```

Comment: this is working like a charm. Only one problem is that if it returns one file, there is still a comma after it. I want it so that if one file is returned, then DO NOT place comma after it. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach my $file ( split(/\s+/,$result) ) {
    $file=~s/\s+//g;
    push(@array,$file);
}
print join(",",@array)
```

Having written this, I would mention that if your script is calling a shell script that does finds, I would recommend looking at File::Find perl module and doing the whole thing in Perl.

Answer (score 0):

You have a string like this:

```
file_list = "file_1
file_2
file_3
file_4"
```

And you want to change it to comma separated.

You can use [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) and [join](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html):

```
 my $comma_separated_list = join ", ", split( /\n/, $nl_separated_file_list );
```

In two separate commands (which may be easier to see):

```
my @file_array = split /\n/, $nl_separated_file_list;
my $comma_separated_list = join ", ", $nl_separated_file_list;
```

The split will produce an array (one for each line. The join will produce a string that is comma separated. The examples here will produce:

$comma_separated_list = "file1, file2, file3, file4, ...";

If you don't want the space, leave it off in the join `", "`.

It is possible to do this with a regular expression (replace each instant of a `\n` with a `,`), but I suspect that will take longer to do than a join/split.