# How to run a bash or shell script in a remote linux server using perl script and ssh

Tags: linux, shell, perl, ssh

I want to run a perl script on a remote server, it should login to a linux server via ssh and run a shell script with an argument, then print the results, please help......

I have a small script which will login and execute the ls command on the remote host, but i want to run a bash script instead.

```
use Net::SSH::Perl;

my $host = "xxxxx";
my $usr = "xxx";
my $pwd = "xxx";
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host);
$ssh->login($usr,$pwd);
my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd("ls -l");
print "$stdout\n";
```

How can I execute the remote shell script instead of "ls -l"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I call a shell command in my Perl script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3200801/608639), [Call a bash script from a perl script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11636721/608639), etc.

Comment: You run any remote command the same way... `$ssh->cmd('whatever');` Doesn't matter what language whatever is implemented in. You might have to include a path if it's not in the remote computer's normal one.

Comment: $ssh->cmd(' ./monitor status '); if run this , i am getting only empty output, i am not getting status output , its a bash script with argument

Comment: Can you show the `$stderr` and `$exit` values for `$ssh->cmd(' ./monitor status ')` ?

Comment: Well there you go. You have to get your program running correctly on the remote computer. Installing whatever package provides that missing library is a good first step.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is fine.   Just replace

```
"ls -l"
```

with

```
"/path/to/my/script arg1 arg2"
```

Note 1 - It's a good idea to use a fully qualified path to your script on the remote.

Note 2 - `arg1` and/or `arg2` can be variables of course.  `$arg1 $arg2`.   If you're not using variables then there is no need for double quotes and you should use single quotes ' instead.

Comment: @AmarendhiranAmar - if you like the answer would you consider up voting and accepting it please?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers