# Shell command inside Perl Script

Tags: regex, perl, unix, grep

All

I have following shell command working as per expectation on shell but not working when invoked inside perl

Shell command:

```
grep -P -s -irl --include \*.v "\s+hello\s?[(].*" <PATH>
```

working fine

Inside Perl:

```
$inst_search = `grep -P -s -irl --include \*.v "\s+$inst\s?[(].*" @plt_dirs`;
```

not working

I am suspecting i am missing something with regexp inside grep..please correct me !

Thanks,
Vivek

Comment: Check this ... If this helps you or not : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200801/how-can-i-call-a-shell-command-in-my-perl-script

Comment: Perl has a `grep` built in. I would suggest using that  rather than a shell escape.

Comment: @Praveen: It's found useful..and solve my problem..Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl will escape special shell characters when calling exec/system/qx (or backticks) with a string.

Try using the exec or system functions, but passing a list, e.g.

```
system('grep', '-P', '-s', '-irl', '--include', '\*.v', '"\s+hello\s?[(].*"', @plt_dirs);
```

You may also want to look at a module that does some of the error handling for you, like IPC::System::Simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$inst_search = qx#grep -P -s -irl --include \*.v "\s+$inst\s?[(].*" @plt_dirs#;
```

Or use any other non-alphanumeric character instead of `"#"`for quoting.