# Command to run Tcl (expect) script from perl script in Ubuntu

Tags: perl, ubuntu, tcl, expect

I was using the below command in windows to run the Tcl (expect) script from a Perl script.

```
system("C:/Tcl/bin/tclsh86 C:/Users/sysadmin/desktop/expect.tcl");
```

Could someone tell me its equivalent command in Ubuntu.

Comment: tclsh /path/expect.tcl ? Assuming you have the toolset installed.

Comment: Yes. Try the command "tclsh /path/expect.tcl" (replace path with correct one).

Comment: I couldn't able to run the expect script directly using perl on windows so i was running this using TCL using system("C:/Tcl/bin/tclsh86 C:/Users/sysadmin/desktop/expect.tcl"); in perl.  But Now i need to run the same on ubuntu so could you please tell what command should be there in perl to execute expect script?
It'd be helpful if you give me the full command.

Comment: Oh, I got it, you want to run expect script from perl script, not from the shell. Sorry, I do not know answer for that, at least not without some investigation.

Comment: It migth make sense to do some googling yourself. Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200801/how-can-i-call-a-shell-command-in-my-perl-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Tcl 8.6 is installed, it's just:

```
system("tclsh8.6 /path/to/expect.tcl");
```

If it isn't installed, fix that with `apt-get install tcl8.6` (which needs to be run as root, of course) or using the package manager GUI.