# Invoke perl script from another perl script

Tags: perl

I am using perl (v5.24.0) on a 64 bit windows machine.

I have two perl scripts "Test1.pl" and "Test2.pl" and I am trying to call "Test2.pl" from "Test1.pl". But I am not seeing the output of the script "Test2"

Test2.pl:--->

```
print "Test2\n";
```

Test1.pl:---->

```
my $iCount = 5;
while($iCount>0)
{
    print "Test1\n";
    sleep(1);
    $iCount--;
}

my $test_script = "C:\\Tests\\Test2.pl";
`perl $test_script`;

$iCount = 5;
while($iCount>0)
{
    print "Test1\n";
    sleep(1);
    $iCount--;
}
```

In the output: I see only Test1 and not Test2.

Note : I have placed both the scripts at the same location.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$output =\`perl $test_script\`; print $output.`

Comment: see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200801/how-can-i-call-a-shell-command-in-my-perl-script)

Comment: @mkHun took the words right out of my keyboard. use `system()` to call the 2nd script. Please close the question if the answer satisfies you.

Comment: Thanks mkHun & user2141046 for your answers. It worked both the ways.
Apologies for the duplicate question.

Comment: `print \`perl $test_script\``