# bash command in Perl script - pass output <( to command

Tags: bash, perl

If I execute following command in bash (debian 10):

```
comm -1 -3  <(sort $file1) <(sort $file2) > $output_file
```

I got the expected result.

But if I try that inside a perl script:

```
`comm -1 -3  <(sort $file1) <(sort $file2) > $output_file`;
```

I got following:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

How could I make it work in perl?

Comment: Just a guess, but is there a chance Perl's using a different shell?  You may find this answer [How can I call a shell command in my Perl script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200801/how-can-i-call-a-shell-command-in-my-perl-script) helpful.

Comment: @radical7 It uses `/bin/sh` or `cmd`. Some people expect `$ENV{SHELL}` to be used, but that makes no sense. Program-provided commands must necessarily target a specific shell, so it makes no sense to use the user's preferred shell. The env var should only be used when creating an interactive shell for the user.

Comment: @ikegami so in a sense, I was right ;-)

Comment: @radical7 You were 100% correct. I was confirming with details.

Answer (score 1):

Backticks use `/bin/sh` (or `cmd`), not `bash`, so you'll need to construct a POSIX shell command. That command could, of course, invoke `bash`.

The following achieves that, while also fixing [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) bugs:

```perl
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $sort_cmd1 = shell_quote( "sort", "--", $file1 ) . ' 2>&1';
my $sort_cmd2 = shell_quote( "sort", "--", $file2 ) . ' 2>&1';
my $bash_cmd  = shell_quote( "comm", "-1", "-3" ) . " <( $sort_cmd1 ) <( $sort_cmd2 )";
my $sh_cmd    = shell_quote( "bash", "-c", $bash_cmd );

my $output = `$sh_cmd`;
```

or

```perl
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $bash_cmd = 'comm -1 -3 <( sort -- "$1" 2>&1 ) <( sort -- "$2" 2>&1 )';
my $sh_cmd = shell_quote( "bash", "-c", $bash_cmd, "dummy", $file1, $file2 );

my $output = `$sh_cmd`;
```